# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in

Tags: php, string, typeerror, offset

Get php fatal error on this line. THIS IS my Code:

```
    $check = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `data` FROM g_product_stream_article WHERE `id_article` = '$IDarticle'";
        try {
            $result = $this->connection->fetchOne($check);
            return ! ($result['data'] === '0');
        }
```

Whats the Problem? What can i do?

i search the solution on google. I changed the return to:

```
return ! (!empty($result['data'] === '0'));
```

but it fails, same error.
I use Shopware.
i got a "TRUE" as return.
My Php version is on 8.0.25. MySql version 5.7.35.

Comment: `var_dump($result);` What do you get? It sounds like `$result` is a string instead of an array

Comment: i got:  string(1) "1"

Comment: You'll need to check the `fetchOne` function to find out why it's returning the string `"1"` instead of an array of results, or if it's just going to return 1/0, then check against `$result` instead of `$result['data']`